# Why is splunk license manager showing very high usage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, splunk

I use splunk together with this addon: https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3110/, which reads text log files from azure blobs. The problem is that license manager shows warnings and eventually search is blocked.
The license manager shows this for my only index:
[image]

At the same time I see that this particular index size is only  1.29 GB. And log files are only several MB per day. How is this possible?

I'm in trial license, but switching to free license does not change this bechaviour.

UPDATE:
Full picture
[image]

Answer (score 1):

License usage is for *all* (except internal) indexes, not just one.  Also, the size of an index is unrelated to the license quota.

The screenshot shows your daily limit is 500MB.  That's fairly easy to exceed with verbose cloud logs.

To see what is using up your quota, go to the Monitoring Console look at the indexing usage broken down by source and/or sourcetype.

Comment: the picture shows indexing usage broken down by source and/or sourcetype. I have only one index. And the file it is indexing is only tens of megabyrtes. Threre is something wrong for sure.

Comment: The image shows ingestion amounts per day.  There is no (apparent) breakdown by any other measure.  Review your inputs and verify you're bringing in only what you expect and that each input file is not being re-indexed.

Comment: I have updated the image, now you can see the breakdown. t400mobileapi index collects data from azure blob storage. Single log file per day is about 50MB. When searching was not blocked I could see that there was no duplicated data in the index.